# Why is $-x = (x^2) ^ {\frac{1}{2}}$ not logically equivalent to $(-x) ^ 2 = ((x^2) ^ {\frac{1}{2}}) ^ 2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

Why is $-x = (x^2) ^ {\frac{1}{2}}$ not logically equivalent to $(-x) ^ 2 = ((x^2) ^ {\frac{1}{2}}) ^ 2$ for all values of x?

First equation:

$-x = (x^2) ^ {\frac{1}{2}}$

Second equation:

$(-x) ^ 2 = ((x^2) ^ {\frac{1}{2}}) ^ 2$

For example, if I plug x = -1 into both equations, only one of them evaluates to true. I would expect both of them to do so because I performed identical operations on both sides. Why are the two equations not logically equivalent?

Comment: what is logically equivalent? Note also that $-x \neq (x^2) ^ {1 / 2}$ if $x\neq 0$

Comment: Try plugging in x =1 . One evaluates to true. The other evaluates to false. Not logically equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are the following equations not equivalent?

$$x = a$$

$$x^2 = a^2$$

Can you figure out why one implies the other but not the other way around?

Comment: Oh. So if the first equation is true for all values of x, then the second equation must be true for all values of x. But the inverse is not true. So the first one implies the second but the second one does not imply the first.

Comment: Correct. Also, here I'm assuming $x^{1/2}$ is taking only the positive square root.

Comment: Yeah. I always thought that x^(1/2) and sqrt(x) were the same thing i.e. that x^(1/2) ALWAYS meant the positive square root. At least that's how it was when I took algebra in eighth grade.

Answer (score 0):

Your first equation does not hold. It would be instead

$-x= -(x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$